# Replacing white spaces to commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Well, i'm using regex to replace all white spaces to commas but there's a white space at the end and i don't know how to make the regex not replace him

What I have

```
25DEL 38DEL A73G
```

JS

```
 var valor = $("#mapaArquivos option:selected").val().replace(/\s+/g, ", ");
```

Output

```
25DEL, 38DEL, A73G,
```

Right Output

```
25DEL, 38DEL, A73G
```

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trim the value before applying regex. this way there will be no trailing or leading spaces

```
var valor = jQuery.trim($("#mapaArquivos option:selected").val())
                  .replace(/\s+/g, ", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could trim the end or you could use

```
replace( /(?!\s+$)\s+/g, ", " );
```

A negative look-ahead prevents trailing spaces being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This should do (it trims the Whitespaces of the initial value first)

```
var valor = $("#mapaArquivos option:selected").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").replace(/\s+/g, ", ");
```

if not, you might want to try `replace(/\s+$/,"")`instead (trims only at the end